# Spring Controller not called from HTML form Submit

Tags: spring

I am trying to call a simple spring controller on the submit action of my HTML Form.
But the spring controller is not getting called. I searched allot but did not understood the missing point. can any one please help on this.

Below is my Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" Xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my spring-servlet.xml is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.src.main"></context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config/>
<mvc:resources location="/page/css/" mapping="/page/css/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/page/content/" mapping="/page/content/**"/>
<!--    <mvc:resources location="/jsp/js/" mapping="/jsp/js/**"/>-->
<bean id="loginBean" class="com.src.main.LoginBean" scope="request">
<aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
<bean id="userLogin" class="com.src.main.UserLogin" scope="session">
<aop:scoped-proxy/> 
</bean>
<bean id="handleApplicationInitProcessor" class="com.src.main.process.HandleApplicationInitProcessor">
<property name="userLogin" ref="userLogin"></property>
<property name="loginBean" ref="loginBean"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

and my jsp is as below:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<f:subview id="user_login_subview">
<html>
<head>
<base href="<%=basePath%>">
<title>My JSP 'userLogin.jsp' starting page</title>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">    
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
<meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
-->
</head>
<body>
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="/processLogin">
<div id="login_div">
<h3 id="login_text" class="borderText">LOGIN</h3>
<div id="user_name_div">
<h:outputText id="loging_label" value="Username :" />
<h:inputText id="login_field" size="30" value="#{loginBean.userName}" tabindex="1" styleClass="textBox"></h:inputText>
</div>
<div id="password_div">
<h:outputText id="password_label" value="Password :" />
<h:inputText id="password_field" size="30" value="#{loginBean.password}" tabindex="2" styleClass="textBox"></h:inputText>
</div>
<div id="remember_me_div">
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="remember_me_checkbox" value="#{loginBean.rememberMe}" tabindex="3" styleClass="checkbox"/>
<h:outputText id="remember_me_label" value="Remember me" />
</div>
<div id="action_buttons_div">
<input type="submit" id="submit_button"  value="submit" class="button"/>
<input type="reset" id="reset_button" value="reset" class="button"/>
</div>
</div>
</form>  
</body>
</html>
</f:subview>
```

and  Controller UserLogin.java is as below,

```
package com.src.main;
public class UserLogin {

private String userName;
private String password;

public UserLogin(){

}
public String getUserName() {
return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword() {
return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}


}
```

And my Controller name is :

```
package com.src.main.process;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.src.main.LoginBean;
import com.src.main.UserLogin;
@Controller
public class HandleApplicationInitProcessor {

private UserLogin userLogin;
private LoginBean loginBean;
public HandleApplicationInitProcessor() {
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/processLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String process(){

this.getUserLogin().setUserName(this.getLoginBean().getUserName());
this.getUserLogin().setPassword(this.getLoginBean().getPassword());
System.err.println("UserName : "+this.getUserLogin().getUserName());
System.err.println("Password : "+this.getUserLogin().getPassword());


return "Hello World !";
}
public UserLogin getUserLogin() {
return userLogin;
}
public void setUserLogin(UserLogin userLogin) {
this.userLogin = userLogin;
}
public LoginBean getLoginBean() {
return loginBean;
}

public void setLoginBean(LoginBean loginBean) {
this.loginBean = loginBean;
}
}
```

Initially i was trying with the  JSF form submit tag but due to this issue i tried with simple HTML form submission but still the same problem. 
I do not get any error on my console as well.

Comment: You are intermixing JSF and Spring Web MVC code. You have not declared DispatcherServlet in web.xml also. Please go through Spring Web MVC getting started tutorial.

Comment: I don't want to use it.  Thats why i have added the requestcontextListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do below changes in your code

1.Declare **DispatcherServlet**  in web.xml file,like below. For Ex:-

```
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

2.Remove below lines from your spring configuration file.

```
<bean id="handleApplicationInitProcessor" class="com.src.main.process.HandleApplicationInitProcessor">
   <property name="userLogin" ref="userLogin"></property>
   <property name="loginBean" ref="loginBean"></property>
</bean>
```

3.Just place `@Autowired` before where you are declaring it(`Controller class`).like below

```
@Autowired
private UserLogin userLogin;
@Autowired
private LoginBean loginBean;
```

4.Remove `<context:annotation-config/>` as you are using `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: my controller gets called if I use this tag and do the mentioned changes.

    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/processLogin">

But Iam getting the null values in my beans, I also tried changing the scope from request to session  as well still getting the null values.

Comment: is your controller called now??

Comment: Change your method in controller like below,pass an argument @RequestBody UserLogin userLogin,which contains the value that you send from your JSP page..

Comment: I am getting HTTP Status 415 -  with below description:
 The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().

Comment: did you make changes in the method of your controller class?

Comment: Below is the method of my controller class:\n

    @RequestMapping(value = "/processLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String process(@RequestBody LoginBean loginBean){
    this.getUserLogin().setUserName(loginBean.getUserName());
    this.getUserLogin().setPassword(loginBean.getPassword());
    System.err.println("UserName : "+this.getUserLogin().getUserName());
   System.err.println("Password : "+this.getUserLogin().getPassword());
    return "Hello World !";
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68174/discussion-between-re350-and-user2039225).

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me with the below changes:
1)  I changed the jsf tag <h:inputText> to simple html <input type="text"> tags and added the
2) HttpServletRequest as a parameter to the method of the controller and took the jsp values via request.getParameter("username")  in the controller.